# Installation guide txt file

Tags: files, documentation, markdown

Is there a standard, guideline, template, how to write this kind of files, for example:

Install-Linux-tar.txt

```
INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS
===============================================================================

  Linux Installation Instructions
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1. Unpack the PhpStorm distribution archive that you downloaded to
     where you wish to install the program. We will refer to this destination
     location as your {installation home} below.

  2. Open a console and cd into "{installation home}/bin" and type:

       ./phpstorm.sh

     to start the application. As a side effect, this will initialize various
     configuration files in the ~/.PhpStorm2018.1 directory.

  3. [OPTIONAL] Add "{installation home}/bin" to your PATH environment
     variable so that you may start PhpStorm from any directory.

  4. [OPTIONAL] To adjust the value of the JVM heap size, create
      ~/.PhpStorm2018.1/phpstorm.vmoptions (or phpstorm64.vmoptions
      if using a 64-bit JDK), and set the -Xms and -Xmx parameters. To see how
      to do this, you can reference the vmoptions file under
      "{installation home}/bin" as a model.

  [OPTIONAL] Changing the location of "config" and "system" directories
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  By default, PhpStorm stores all your settings under the ~/.PhpStorm2018.1/config
  directory and uses ~/.PhpStorm2018.1/system as a data cache.
  If you want to change these settings,

  1. Open a console and cd into ~/.PhpStorm2018.1/config

  2. Create the file "idea.properties" and open it in an editor. Set the
     idea.system.path and/or idea.config.path variables as desired, for
     example:

     idea.system.path=~/custom/system
     idea.config.path=~/custom/config

  3. Note that we recommend to store data cache ("system" directory) on a disk
     with at least 1GB of free space.




Enjoy!

-PhpStorm Development Team
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. It's called [asciidoc](https://asciidoc.org/).

> AsciiDoc is a text document format for writing notes, documentation,
> articles, books, ebooks, slideshows, web pages, man pages and blogs.
> AsciiDoc files can be translated to many formats including HTML, PDF,
> EPUB, man page.

I have not verified whether your PhpStorm example is also AsciiDoc, but it is very likely.